# Variable not getting assigned in bash after a curl hit

Tags: bash, curl, sed

I have a shell script where I have a statement:

```
isPartial = $searchCurl| grep -Po '\"partialSearch\":(true|false)'|sed 's/\\\"partialSearch\\\"://'
```

now, if I just echo the RHS

```
 $searchCurl| grep -Po '\"partialSearch\":(true|false)'|sed 's/\\\"partialSearch\\\"://'
```

it prints `"partialSearch":true`, but the variable `isPartial` doesn't get initialized .

Why is this happening and how can I fix it ?

Comment: You want a [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution): `isPartial=$( ... )`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the number of backslashes in your examples varies, it is not clear to me if the double quotes are already escaped in the input text. I’ll assume they are not, i.e. the input text looks something like:

```
sometext... "partialSearch":true ... sometext... 
..bla bla bla... "partialsearch":false ...
```

and my examples below will work under this assumption.

There are a number of points to be made.

- You seem to be trying to parse JSON input with regular expressions. While this could be acceptable for quick-and-dirty one-time jobs where you know the exact format of the data being processed, in general it is a **very** bad idea. You should use a JSON parser like `jq`.
- You obviously have stored some bash code in the variable `searchCurl`. This is considered bad practice. Instead of `searchCurl="... code ..."` you should do `function searchCurl () { ... code ... }` and call `searchCurl` without prefixing it with a dollar sign. Variables are for values, functions are for code.
- In most cases, if you are going to use `sed`, it’s better to use it for everything without invoking `grep`. Sometimes it can be simpler to have both. See below for an example.
- To assign the output of a command to a variable, you have to use command substitution.

In short, if in your input text you have only one match of `'"partialSearch":(true|false)'`, this is what you want:

```
isPartial=$(searchCurl|sed -rn 's/^.*"partialSearch":(true|false).*$/\1/p')
```

If you have more and the input text is one big line as I suppose, usage of `grep -o` might simplify the task of splitting the input into one match per line, so that

```
isPartial=$(searchCurl|grep -Po '"partialSearch":(true|false)'|sed -e 's/^.*://')
```

might be what you want (and in this case, `isPartial` will hold a space-separated list of `true` and `false`).